# Constructing irreducible representations of quaternion group over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am a beginner in studying the representation theory and I am doing some exercises in this field. So this is not a homework.

My question is about constructing all irreducible representations of quaternion group over the field of rational numbers. I know that this group has four $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible representations of degree 1 (with value in {1,-1}) and one $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible representation of degree 2. It is obvious that its $\mathbb{C}$-irreducible representations of degree 1 are also $\mathbb{Q}$-irreducible representations. Also, we can construct a representation for this group over $\mathbb{Q}$ as follows:

[image: quaternion]

My questions are:

**1-What is the best way to show that this representation is irreducible?**

**2-How can I prove that the only irreducible representations of $Q_8$ over rational field  are of degrees 1,1,1,1,4?**

Because this is an exercise of section 8.3 of the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups by Robinson", I think that this problem can be solvable using the material contained in it. If I should know something special about representations over $\mathbb{Q}$ and have much information on this topic, please guide me about that.

I with be so appreciate for your helpful answers.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The existence of a common eigenvector is equivalent to the representation having a $1$-dimensional constituent. But, as a complex representation, this one is a sum of two copies of the $2$-dimensional complex irreducible - you can show that easily from the character values. So I don't think your method will work on this example.

Comment: Since the representation is a sum of two complex $2$-dimensional representations, to show it is irreducible over ${\mathbb Q}$, it would be enough to show that $Q_8$ has no $2$-dimensional irreducible representation over ${\mathbb Q}$ which can be done by an elementary calculation with matrices.

Comment: @Derek: I can see from the representation of 1,-1,i and -i that this representation is a sum of 2 complex representations, but what about j,-j,k,-k?Also how can I prove that these representations are the only ones over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't understand your first question "what about $j,-j,k,-k$"! You said that you can see that it is the sum of two complex representations, so what's the problem? As for the second question, it is difficult to help without knowing what general results you know. In general, if you have a collection of irreducible representations of a finite group over a subfield of ${\mathbb C}$ which, when regarded as a collection of complex representations, contains all complex irreducibles as constituents, then you have a complete set of irreducibles over the subfield.

Comment: @DerekHolt: As I told in my first comment, I have studied chapter 8 of the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups, by Robinson" and I know representation and character theory as much as I read from that book. I don't understand why this representation contains all irreducible as constituents and why it is a sum of two complex representation.

Comment: Do you know the character values of the $2$-dimensional complex representation?

Comment: Yes. These values are $2,-2,0,0,0$ for conjugacy classes $\{1\}$, $\{-1\}$, $\{+i,-i\}$, $\{+j,-j\}$ and $\{+k,-k\}$, respectively.

Comment: In that case, you can see immediately, just by looking at the traces of the above $4 \times 4$ matrices, that your representation is equivalent to the sum of two copies of the $2$-dimensional complex representation. Remember that two complex representations are equivalent iff all of their character values are equal. (That's why they are called characters.)

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you very much for your helpful guidance and answers.